# How to convert a milliseconds date to a DateTime?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have this time from an server: 1475245457452
The Date and Time for this is: 30.9.2016, 16:24:17

How can I convert this 1475245457452 in Delphi to a correct Date and Time?

Comment: Have you checked out the `DateUtils` unit?

Comment: I re-tagged your question taking a guess at your version. There is no XE10. My guess is Berlin, but it won't make a difference either way.

Comment: I corrected the header to read *milli*seconds instead of *micro*seconds, as the value you provided is indeed milliseconds (from Unix epoch).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did not say, but I can guess that this quantity is actually milliseconds, measured from the Unix epoch. So convert them using [`UnixToDateTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.UnixToDateTime) from the `System.DateUtils` unit:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.DateUtils;

begin
  Writeln(DateTimeToStr(UnixToDateTime(1475245457452 div 1000)));
end.
```

I have divided by `1000` to convert into seconds because `UnixToDateTime` expects the time in seconds rather than milliseconds.
If you wish to retain the millisecond part of the time then you can readily increment the date time value by the remainder of the division.

It is important to stress that time is always measured in some unit system, and relative to some origin, or epoch. It's never enough to know just a value, but you have to know both the units and the epoch. Yes, it is often easy enough to guess these, but it would usually be better to read the specification of the software producing the time value to find out definitively what the value is.

Comment: Thank you! This is the suloution.

Comment: @Pascal if this is the correct solution, please mark the answer as correct